# Bootstrap popover is not working but same is working if i use debugger

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

**HTML Code**

```
  <button id="btnDeviceTypePop" type="button" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="right" class="btn btn-info btn-xs" title="DeviceType">?</button>
```

**Javascript Code**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var resultSet = { WEB: 1, PCMAC: 2, IOS: 3, ANDROID: 4, BLACKBERRY: 5, WINDOWS: 6, OTHER: 7, MAC: 8, Kindle: 9 };
    var popContent = "";
    for (var key in resultSet) {
        // check if the property/key is defined in the object itself, not in parent
        if (resultSet.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            popContent += "<div class='popover-seperator'>" + key + "</div>";
        }
    }
    $("#btnDeviceTypePop").popover({
        html: true,
        content: function () {
            return popContent
        },
    }).on('click', function () {
        $(this).popover('toggle')
    });

});
```

**When I use debugger in Javascript code of popover function, popover is working as shown in the below picture. However, if I click on button without debugger then it's not working. Not sure what's going on. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!**

[Output when I use debugger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4oUn9.png)

[Debugger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/luZw2.png)

Comment: assuming you're using chrome and you've added a breakpoint by clicking on the line number, it pauses execution on that line without running it. remove the breakpoint or step over the call.

Comment: I have used firefox. If I step over then it is not working. Thanks!